# How to get updated form values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I created some forms and dropdowns and got Javascript to find the values of the forms and dropdowns.

However, when I try to print these values I get either the default value of the dropdown or 'undefined' for a form, even when I've put text into them. How can I update the values?

There are several similar questions posted, I know, but I don't know whether their answers are relevant to my situation because I am new to Javascript.

Anyway the full page can be found via pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/DpcrsfxN.

Comment: `value` gets the selected value. also, put some simplified code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
var oDayField = oForm.elements["day"]
```

Use

```
var oDayField = oForm.day;
```

and then to update the value of this input you'd simply do

```
oDayField.value = "New Value";
```

---

Also, it looks like you have this script right out in the open, after your body section:

```
var oReplacementNameField = oForm.elements["repname"]
var repname = oReplacementNameField.value;

function printVariables() {
        document.write(repname)
}
```

This will always print the default value of the input when the user submits the form because you're reading and saving this value right after the page is rendered.

You'll want to read these values fresh from inside of the `printVariables` function

```
var oForm = document.forms["postgen"];
var oReplacementNameField = oForm.repname;

function printVariables() {
    var repname = oReplacementNameField.value;

    document.write(repname)
}
```

Comment: This is very handy +1, it looks that I will need to fav the question, just to find your reply. I dream on a future where I can fav answers (and not just questions)

Comment: @ajax333221 - thanks for the kind words - glad the answer helped!

Comment: Okay so I made the changes you suggested. When I hit the Generate button, nothing happens. How do I link the form, the button, and the Javascript up so that upon hitting the button, I actually get output in the form of `repname`? Thanks for all your work.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to read variables from inside the function, at any rate!